# How to get more than cows from cowsay

Tags: configuration, customization, fortune, cowsay

I have recently installed `cowsay` and am using it to amuse me by piping the output from `fortune` to it. And although this is great, I understand that you can get more than just cows with `cowsay`, and I have looked in `/usr/share/cowsay/cows` and found the following files:

```
apt.cow                ghostbusters.cow  sheep.cow
beavis.zen.cow         gnu.cow           skeleton.cow
bong.cow               head-in.cow       snowman.cow
bud-frogs.cow          hellokitty.cow    sodomized-sheep.cow
bunny.cow              kiss.cow          stegosaurus.cow
calvin.cow             kitty.cow         stimpy.cow
cheese.cow             koala.cow         suse.cow
cock.cow               kosh.cow          three-eyes.cow
cower.cow              luke-koala.cow    turkey.cow
daemon.cow             mech-and-cow.cow  turtle.cow
default.cow            meow.cow          tux.cow
dragon-and-cow.cow     milk.cow          unipony.cow
dragon.cow             moofasa.cow       unipony-smaller.cow
duck.cow               moose.cow         vader.cow
elephant.cow           mutilated.cow     vader-koala.cow
elephant-in-snake.cow  pony.cow          www.cow
eyes.cow               pony-smaller.cow
flaming-sheep.cow      ren.cow
```

Which all seem to be different cool things like this was the contents of `ghostbusters.cow`:

[image]

So my question is, how do I activate all these other fun creatures? And can I get it to pick one at random for each strange message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve what you want run :

```
fortune | cowsay -f ghostbusters
```

[image]

---

And for random ... :

```
fortune | cowsay -f `ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/ | shuf -n 1`
```

[image]

Comment: Just to add to the above, and kind of surprisingly, `man cowsay` and `man fortune` are actually helpful for anyone else that happens to come across this question/answer.

Comment: Is there a way to show all available images at once?

Answer (score 0):

After you go to `/usr/share/cowsay/cow`, type:

```
lolcat skeleton.cow
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see the tweaked contents of my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file addition at the bottom.  Also in there you will find what ended up being my `/home/$USER$/.config/neofetch/config.conf` file.

Make backups of your files as necessary.  I didn't and now I'm stuck with the knowledge of how to do it forever because I used Google.

[Sample pic of my terminal running with my tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kXCq.png)

https://pastebin.com/gZSj4ub9#KKtmzNZ4

Fully randomized woke cow scene in your terminal, lolcat'd and spittin' sassy fortunes at you with date/weather updates -- each. and. every. time. you. open. the. terminal. :)

It even displays in both nemo-terminals with a split-view. xD  Two different fortunes each time you open your file browser/manager, which also happens to support terminal plugins.........